# Optimizing Mysql Query

Tags: mysql

This is the query that I'm looking to optimize:

```
SELECT Id, Title, Text,
(SELECT count(*) from ReaderFeedback as b
where b.EmailAddress=ReaderFeedback.EmailAddress) AS totalPosts
FROM ReaderFeedback FORCE INDEX (ParentFeedbackId)
WHERE ParentFeedbackId = 123 AND Approved=1 ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Below is the Mysql explain query results:

```
    id: 1
    select_type: PRIMARY
    table: ReaderFeedback
    Type: ref
    possible_keys :ParentFeedbackId
    Key: ParentFeedbackId
    key_len: 7
    ref: const,const
    rows: 2
    Extra: Using where; Using filesort

    id: 2
    DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
    b
    ALL
    NULL
    NULL
    NULL
    NULL
    101369
    Using where
```

Show create table freader feedback if below:

```
CREATE TABLE `ReaderFeedback` (
`Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ParentFeedbackId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Text` text NOT NULL,
`Title` varchar(75) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`EmailAddress` varchar(75) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
`Approved` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1',
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
KEY `ParentFeedbackId` (`ParentFeedbackId`,`Approved`),
KEY `Title` (`Title`),
KEY `Id` (`Id`),
KEY `Approved` (`Approved`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=142781 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Please help out a fellow developer.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show us the explain plan? (ie. `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ..`.) Also show us your `show create table ReaderFeedback`

Comment: Yeah you should consider my answer below. adding the index that I mention,and changing your query to a join will perform better for sure. Also, consider changing your engine to innodb instead of MyISAM

Comment: wonderfully helpful, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's break this down.

First, you're using a correlated subquery to get the post count.  Let's turn that into a joined aggregate subquery. This gets you the count of rows for each distinct email address.

```
      SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count,
             EmailAddress
        FROM ReaderFeedback
       GROUP BY EmailAddress
```

Then, let's join that into your other query, like so.

```
SELECT a.Id, a.Title, a.Text
       b.Count
  FROM ReaderFeedback AS as
  JOIN (
          SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count,
                 EmailAddress
            FROM ReaderFeedback
           GROUP BY EmailAddress
       ) AS b ON a.EmailAddress = b.EmailAddress
 WHERE a.ParentFeedbackID = 123
   AND a.Approved = 1
 ORDER BY a.Date ASC
```

That should perform a little better than what you have already.

Going further than that involves experimenting with indexes. Here are some things to try.

1. Create a compound index on `(ParentFeedbackID, Approved, EmailAddress, Date)`. This may (or may not) help satisfy the outer query.
2. Create an index on `(EmailAddress)`. This will very likely help satisfy the inner `GROUP BY` query.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your table structure and the explain plan for the query it is hard to offer much help

But, try this query as it should give you better results.

```
SELECT R.Id, R.Title, R.Text, b.totalPosts
FROM ReaderFeedback R
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT EmailAddress, count(*) AS totalPosts
    FROM ReaderFeedback
    WHERE ParentFeedbackId = 123 AND Approved=1
    GROUP BYEmailAddress
) AS b ON b.EmailAddress = R.EmailAddress
WHERE R.ParentFeedbackId = 123 AND R.Approved=1 
ORDER BY R.Date
```

In addition, you should have add an index (if it does not already exists) on the `ReaderFeedback`  table like so

```
ALTER TABLE ReaderFeedback  ADD INDEX (EmailAddress, ParentFeedbackId , Approved, Date);
```

Also, consider changing your Table engine from MyISAM to INNODB.

```
ALTER TABLE ReaderFeedback ENGINE=INNODB;
```

You can also change your `EmailAddress` column  to `CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci` as this will make the lookup part quicker.

```
ALTER TABLE ReaderFeedback CHANGE `EmailAddress` EmailAddress VARCHAR(75) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
```

Good Luck!